# Why Http request never ends

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I am doing http request in nodejs, but the request never ends and proceed to do its following code. it only prints out "response end", but never "request end". Why will it behave like this?

```
const post_data = JSON.stringify({
    'username': username,
    'org': orgName,
    'peers': peers,
    'channelName': channelName,
    'chaincodeName': chaincodeName,
    'fcn': fcn,
    'args': args
});

var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3000',
    path: '/cc/write',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         "content-type": "application/json",
         "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
    }
};

var post_req = http.request(post_options, function (res) {
    console.log("connected");
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
        ccResponse = chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log('response end')
    });
});

// post the data
post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.on('end', function () {
    console.log('request end');
});
post_req.on('finish', function () {
    console.log('request end');
});
post_req.end();

console.log("Random thing");
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? The "end" event of the HTTP response is the end of your Client -> server interaction. There is no such thing as "end" of HTTP request on its own.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra bracket right above the last line `console.log("Random thing");`
After removing that bracket the code produced this log:

```
Random thing
request end
connected
Response: {"error":"Not Found"}
response end
```

As you can see there is 'request end' in the log.
It was run with node v11.13.0.

Please let me know if it doesn't help.

The actual code that I used:

```js
const http = require('http');

const post_data = JSON.stringify({
    'username': 'username',
    'org': 'orgName',
    'peers': 'peers',
    'channelName': 'channelName',
    'chaincodeName': 'chaincodeName',
    'fcn': 'fcn',
    'args': 'args'
});

var post_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3000',
    path: '/cc/write',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         "content-type": "application/json",
         "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
    }
};

var post_req = http.request(post_options, function (res) {
    console.log("connected");
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
        ccResponse = chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log('response end')
    });
});

// post the data
post_req.write(post_data);
post_req.on('end', function () {
    console.log('request end');
});
post_req.on('finish', function () {
    console.log('request end');
});
post_req.end();

console.log("Random thing");
```

Comment: That's actually my typo in here as I am originally putting the whole http request inside a "if", and I did not remove it when I post the code. Sorry about misleading you.

Comment: @lmc1913 have you tried to put the code from this snippet in a new project? It might be something wrong with node or even with other code that you haven't shown yet. If this works for me on node 11.13.0, it should work for you as well. And if it doesn't, that means only one thing - it's not the code problem.